# Lazy load angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm building an angular app and I want to load my components only when that route has been requested. I thought something like this might work

```
const states = [{
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login?sessid',
    component: 'login',
    resolve: {
      login: () => import('./components/login.js').then(login => {
        login.default.register()
      }),
    },
}];
```

Where the login component is

```
export default {
      register() {
        angular.module('trending')
          .component('login', () => ({
              template: 'Hello!'
            })
        )
    }
};
```

But I get an error

```
angular.js?10a4:13708 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
loginDirectiveProvider <- loginDirective
```

Presumably because the login component isn't registered before the state is. I realize that this is abusing the purpose of the resolve property, I just hoped it would work for my needs. What's a better way to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: OCLAZYLOAD Example app here http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-lazy-load-modules-controllers-angularjs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the app gets bootstrapped, you can't declare a component anymore. So, in order to register a component at run time, you have to expose, somehow, the respective factories. The code bellow exposes all factories on the main app module, but you can use only the component's if you prefer.

```
const app = angular.module('trending', []);

app.config(($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) => {
    app.register = {
        component: $compileProvider.component,
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
        directive: $compileProvider.directive,
        filter: $filterProvider.register,
        factory: $provide.factory,
        service: $provide.service
    };
});
```

This way, you just have to call `app.register.component` to access the exposed factory. For example, taken from your question:

```
export default {
      register() {
        angular.module('trending')
          .register
          .component('login', () => ({
              template: 'Hello!'
            })
        )
    }
};
```

> You might find a fancier way to register your modules, this is just a demonstration for the sake of the answer, you can either change the nomenclature used or even the exposing mechanism to fit better on your fancy `es6+` components.